# Cubic diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, cubics

I am trying to solve the Diophantine equation $xy^2 + 2xy + x - 243y = 0$.

I simplified it to $x(y^2 +2y +1) = 243y$ but I am stuck on what to do now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : $y$ and $y+1$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to find solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?
The pair $(0,0)$ is a solution.

You can simplify further $x(y+1)^2=243y$.

We know that $y\mid x(y+1)^2$. But $\operatorname{gcd}(y,(y+1)^2)=1$. You can proof that simply.

So $y\mid x$. And we can express $x=yc$. Which would lead to a cubic equation in $y$, which you can solve, as $y$ now accours in every term, we even can factor this, which then leads to a quadratic equation. This can be solved easily with the known formulas/methods.

Comment: @A.J. Thanks for pointing that out. I missed it, because I didnt do the calculation, once I have seen we can epress $x$ in terms of $y$. Indeed, this makes it really simple. I will edit that.

Comment: Can you explain how you know that y∣x(y+1)^2.  I'm lost on that part.

Comment: I believe I have it figured out to c=243/(y+1)^2.  This should be able to help me figure out the integer solutions.  I came up with 3 positive and 3 negative solutions.  I am just not sure on the notation yet of y∣x(y+1)^2.  Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @60minutemen $y\mid x(y+1)^2$ is supposed to mean $y$ divides $x(y+1)^2$. So by definition there is an integer number c with $yc=x(y+1)^2$. As noted in my answer it turns out that we can even conclude that $y\mid x$, which is very helpful. It is a basic theme in solving such equations, that you reduce them modulo something, and look at the devisors. As the RHS in the equations you proposed is 243y (a product of 243 and y) we know that 243 and y is also a devisor of the LHS.

Comment: Ahh.  Yes, that makes sense.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @60minutemen You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ and $y$ are integers satisfying your equation, then also
$$3^5y=243y=x(y^2+2y+1)=x(y+1)^2.$$
Because $y$ and $y+1$ have no common divisor, it follows that $(y+1)^2$ divides $3^5$. Can you finish from here?

> It follows that $(y+1)^2=3^{2k}$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2\}$ and so $y=-1\pm3^k$, and $$x=\frac{3^5y}{(y+1)^2}=3^{5-2k}y.$$ Checking these few values of $k$ yields the following six solutions $(x,y)$: $$(0,0),\quad(-486,-2),\quad(54,2),\quad(-108,-4),\quad(24,8),\quad(-30,-10).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xy^2 + 2xy + x - 243y =(x)y^2+(2x-343)y+x=0 \implies x=0,y=0$$
$$y = \frac{(243-2x) \pm 9 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{243 - 4 x}}{(2 x)}
\quad\text{for}\quad -1500\le x \le 1500\\
\implies (x,y)=(-486,-2)\quad (-108,-4)\quad (-30,-10)\quad 
(24,8)\quad (54,2)\quad $$